# Input no despliega popup de carga de archivos una vez es enviado. AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, formularios, input

Trabajando con AngularJS en un formulario de carga de archivos, una vez que realicé una carga y envié dichos archivos, no me permite cargar nuevos elementos.
La dinámica del problema es el siguiente: En un input, manejado mediante el atributo *uploader* (objeto de tipo `new FileUploader()`), se cargan múltiples archivos, y los archivos agregados son visualizados de manera dinámica.

```html
<div class='form-group'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><span class="center-label">Documentación</span></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
      <input class="upload_input" ng-show="!isUploadingFile" type="file" nv-file-select="" multiple="" uploader="uploaderFile" accept="image/*" id="inputImg"><label class="upload_label"><i class="fa fa-picture-o picture-color" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{fileName}}</label>
      <p ng-repeat="currentFile in uploaderFile.queue" class="btn-delete-container"> {{currentFile.file.name}} <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-delete" ng-click="currentFile.remove()"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></p>
      <div ng-if="isUploadingFile" class="small-loading"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Para realizar el envío de los archivos, se ejecuta la función `fileChanged()` asociada al evento click de un botón:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    <div class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="fileChanged(auth)">
      <span ng-show="!spinnerRequestAutorization">Enviar solicitud</span>
      <span ng-show="spinnerRequestAutorization"><i class="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Esta función dispara un evento asincrono manejado desde el módulo de javcascript asociado a este archivo html:

```js
var uploaderFile = $scope.uploaderFile = new FileUploader();
uploaderFile.filters.push({
  name: 'extension',
  fn: function(item, options) {
    var type = '|' + item.type.slice(item.type.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '|';
    return '|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|tiff|tif|'.indexOf(type) !== -1;
  }
});
uploaderFile.filters.push({
  name: 'bytes',
  fn: function(item, options) {
    return $scope.selectImage(item);
  }
});

$scope.fileChanged = function() {
    function listSuccess(response) {
      $scope.auth = angular.copy($scope.resetObj);
      $scope.uploaderFile.queue = angular.copy($scope.resetList);
      $scope.showMessegerExit = true;
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.showMessegerExit = false;
      }, TIME_ERROS);
      $scope.file = null;
      $scope.spinnerRequestAutorization = false;
    }

    function listError(response) {
      $scope.auth = angular.copy($scope.resetObj);
      $scope.uploaderFile.queue = angular.copy($scope.resetList);
      $scope.authorizations.$setPristine();
      $scope.showMessegerERROR = true;
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.showMessegerERROR = false;
      }, TIME_ERROS);
      $scope.spinnerRequestAutorization = false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.uploaderFile.queue.length; i++) {
      $scope.fileList.push($scope.uploaderFile.queue[i]._file);
    }
    $scope.isUploadingFile = true;
    $scope.spinnerRequestAutorization = true;

    var payload = {
      file: $scope.fileList,
      ...
    };

    $servicioDeEjemplo.metodoDeEjemplo(payload).then(listSuccess, listError);
```

Cabe aclarar que `$scope.resetObj = {}` y `$scope.resetList = []`.

Una vez que los archivos son cargados y es diparada la función `$scope.fileChanged()`, se genera el *payload* y se realiza la petición a la API mediante el servicio. La respuesta es manejada por la función `listSuccess()` en caso de ser satisfactoria y, por `listError()`, en caso de ser negativa. Funciones que emiten un alerta correspondiente y resetean el uploader.

***En este momento deberíamos poder volver a cargar archivos en el input y realizar un nuevo envío. Pero eso es imposible, ya que el input no registra el evento click y no abre el popup del explorador de archivos, por lo que es imposible cargar más. Pareciera ser que fue desahilitado de alguna manera. Ocurre con todos los inputs de esa página.***

***Eliminé todo el código innecesario para pruebas y llegué a la conclusión de que ocurre cuando se realiza el click en el botón de envío.***

Desde ya muchas gracias, y cualquier duda o falta de explicación, coméntenlo y les responderé a la brevedad.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondo yo mismo la pregunta porque despues de unos días, un colega me hizo llegar la respuesta y quería dejar registro de la solución al problema, por si alguno lo tiene.

La cuestión radica en que, ni la función **listSuccess()**, ni en la función **listError()**, devuelven la variable *isUploadingFile*, nuevamente a *false*. Por lo que se debe agregar la línea

```
$scope.isUploadingFile = false;
```

dentro de las funciones **listSuccess()** y **listError()**.

Espero que les sirva. Saludos